# How to use device_calendar plugin in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar, flutter-dependencies

I'm developing an application where the user can add a reminder in their local calendar from our app.

The user selects the date and time, and books a service. After the booking, I want to provide them with a button that takes them to the calendar app and creates an event filled with given date, time and title.

I've tried to use the [device_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/device_calendar) plugin for this but the documentation is not clear to me.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az4PW.png) - This is a screenshot of a demo app with the time, date and service name. *When user clicks on the calendar button, it opens their device's calendar with a new event on this date and time with the service name as title.*

Code/Resources I've tried till now:

- Example on device_calendar github. (Not easy to understand) [Link](https://github.com/builttoroam/device_calendar/tree/develop/example)
- This article. (Lots of errors and outdated dependencies) [Link](https://itnext.io/using-device-calendar-library-in-flutter-to-communicate-with-android-ios-calendar-95b2d8c77b40)

Comment: Hi @Anushka Chauhan , can you use this  plugin 'add_2_calendar'? Are you need any example?

Comment: Try this chinni .. https://itnext.io/using-device-calendar-library-in-flutter-to-communicate-with-android-ios-calendar-95b2d8c77b40

Comment: Can you include your code that you've tried so far?

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh I've added the resources I've referred to thus far. Please check them out.

Answer (score 0):

I think that for your purpose you should use this plugin: [add_2_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/add_2_calendar).
It basically triggers an intent towards calendar apps.

[device_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/device_calendar) provides methods to interact with calendars without exiting from app.

I hope this helped you!

Answer (score 0):

i used following packages
**device_calendar: ^4.3.0
flutter_native_timezone:**
this is working perfectly in my app.
events are created sucessfully and display into my device calendar.

```
 await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    var eventToCreate = Event(
      "1",
      //  eventId: "50",
      title: "calendarEventModel 12345",
      description: "eventDescription",
      start: TZDateTime.now(currentLocation),
      end: TZDateTime.now(currentLocation).add(Duration(hours: 10)),
    );
    
    final createEventResult =
        await deviceCalendarPlugin.createOrUpdateEvent(eventToCreate);
    if (createEventResult!.isSuccess) {
      Utils.showTopMessage("Event added to Calendar", Colors.green);
      Get.back();
    }
```

git hub issue link here

> https://github.com/builttoroam/device_calendar/issues/123#issuecomment-1475162288
>
> Blockquote